# Report server web service (SSRS report/SOAP api)

Tags: web-services, soap, reporting-services, reportserver

I have a requirement like this: 
 I have to create **Report server soap web service**. I have googled so many things not even single clue i got about creating **Report server web service**. Can anyone explain me what is this ? What is Report server web service? how it differs from normal asp.net web services to Report server web service? I read some links. from those i just got basic understanding of  report service web service. [Report Server Web Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/report-server-web-service?view=sql-server-2017)   &  [Accessing the SOAP API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/accessing-the-soap-api?view=sql-server-2017)   &[Report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/methods/report-server-web-service-methods?toc=%2Fsql%2Freporting-services%2Freport-server-web-service%2Fmethods%2Ftoc.json&view=sql-server-2017)   &  [Building Applications Using the Web Service and the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/net-framework/building-applications-using-the-web-service-and-the-net-framework?view=sql-server-2017) **so on.**
there is no proper example of how to create **Report server soap web service**

Comment: How can i start creating report server web service in .net? and how to consume them?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a SSRS webservice. The SQL Server Report Server already has one integrated. It's documented by Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/accessing-the-soap-api.